# Automatically mapping subdomains to directories with Apache 2.4?

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, subdomain, directory

I manage a lot of projects on my personal development server. I just upgraded Apache and accidentally reset the configuration files in the process, so I thought this was a good opportunity to optimize my setup.

Before, I had one virtual host which pointed to a directory containing a bunch of project directories. That way I could just go to `mydomain.com/MyProject`. This works okay, but has some problems with certain kinds of linking.

I would vastly prefer to automatically map `myProjectOne.mydomain.com` to the `myProjectOne` directory. (I assume this behavior will always be case-insensitive because I'm using a subdomain instead of a directory name.)

I found [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/182901/automatic-subdomains-with-apache) that seems to be the answer. But when I used this approach, I got a 404 error.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  VirtualDocumentRoot /home/MyUsername/Projects/%0
  ServerName mydomain.com
  ServerAlias *.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Also, I see a potential problem with this setup. My domain does point to my servers, and all the ports are configured correctly...however, I can't access that domain when I'm at home and on the same internal network as my servers.

Is there a setup that would do the same thing but would also allow me to utilize `subdomain.localhost` or `subdomain.10.0.0.*`?

What's the problem here?

Comment: Three things to check- is UseCanonicalName Off? Add a trailing slash to the VirtualDocumentRoot path? And check on case sensitivity, my recollection is that case is normalized.

Comment: I have not configured `UseCanonicalName`. Let me try that.

Comment: Just tried all the combinations of turning `UseCanonicalName` on and off on the virtual host, changing the case of the directory, and with and without the `/`. Still "The requested URL / was not found on this server."

Comment: Ah, looks like this wants %1 rather than %0. The former renders just the subdomain, the latter renders the entire domain. Reference: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/weblinux2/apache/ch04_04.htm

Comment: *"however, I can't access that domain when I'm at home and on the same internal network as my servers."* that's probably because you have either a hosts file or made the [unfortunate design choice](http://serverfault.com/q/76715/37681) to name your AD domain after your registered domain name rather than using a subdomain of that domain name...

Comment: Check this answer which might help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/18759855/272180